# unable to sudo apt --fix-broken install python3-venv package

Tags: python, linux

```
$ sudo apt install python3-venv
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc6-i386 : Depends: libc6 (= 2.31-13+deb11u3) but 2.31-13+deb11u2 is to be installed
 libc6-x32 : Depends: libc6 (= 2.31-13+deb11u3) but 2.31-13+deb11u2 is to be installed
 python3-venv : Depends: python3.9-venv (>= 3.9.2-0~) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: python3 (= 3.9.2-3) but 3.9.2-2 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: "You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these". Did you do that?

Comment: I tried but the problem is not solved, the error is coming.

Comment: Well, what happened when you tried `apt --fix-broken install`?